# I need a dynamic URL rewrite using a subdirectory and query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I can't seem to get this rewrite working correctly. I'm looking for a url such as:

```
`http://sub.domain.com/directory/index.php?name=value`
```

To dynamically rewrite as:

```
`http://sub.domain.com/directory/value`
```

Any help? Currently I am using:

```
`RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ directory/index.php?name=$1 [L]`
```

But this is not giving me the desired rewrite. Instead the rewritten URI that this rule creates look like:

```
`http://sub.domain.com/directory/index/name/value`
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]*)$ /directory/index.php?name=$1 [L]

(I always use: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php)